# Referencing a figure, table or citation

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I want to refer to any figure, table or citations in my text so that if I click on the reference (or link) it will take me to the actual figure, table or citation. Currently, it is not happening for me in the pdf I generate with LaTeX. Should I have to add any package for that?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the `hyperref` package for this. In the code below I have added some customization as a starting point because it is also frequently asked about.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    backref =       true,
    pagebackref  =  true,
    colorlinks =    true,
    linkcolor =     [rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.8},
    anchorcolor =   [rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.8},
    citecolor =     [rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.8},
    filecolor =     [rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.8},
    urlcolor =      [rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.8},
    pdftitle=       {Title},
    pdfsubject=     {Title},
    pdfauthor=      {A. Uthor}
}
```

Comment: If all colors are to be the same, you can provide a single instruction, viz., `allcolors = blue` (or whatever other color you like).