# back references within "thebibliography"

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

I'm using a very simple bibliography, without BibLaTeX, but just with a `thebibliography` environment. Something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    backref =       true,
    pagebackref  =  true,
    colorlinks =    true
}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Test}
    This is a test. \cite{item1}

    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{item1} “Information Management: a Proposal” (1989)\\
        \url{http://www.w3.org/History/1989/proposal.html}
    \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make back-references for such bibitems without using BibLaTeX? I would like to have when passing on “Information Management: a Proposal” you can click on and come back to the citation page. Is it possible?

Comment: hi Enrico @egreg Last time you helped me to solve a nice problem. Thanks so much. Please, if you know how, can you help me to solve this bibliography issue? Thank you.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) :)

Comment: Please always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), one which starts with `\documentclass` and ends in `\end{document}`. Does this post answers your problem? [Referencing a figure, table or citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43377)

Comment: @hpesoj626 It doesn't solve the issue. I get this error messages:
code Package hyperref Warning: Option backref' has already been used,
(hyperref) setting the option has no effect on input line 18.
Package hyperref Warning: Option pagebackref' has already been used,
(hyperref) setting the option has no effect on input line 18.

Comment: @user2041321 is this [writelatex example made by me](https://www.writelatex.com/100445dwwcwq) which you are looking for ?

Comment: @user2041321 What issue? You didn't mention an error message in your question. Can you edit your post and include an MWE that shows your problem?

Comment: @texenthusiast no, it isn't.

Comment: BTW, you mention that you want to click on the title and go to the citation page. But what if you cite a work more than once? That's why usually back references are printed, eg. as page numbers after each entry.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Sorry, I was wrong: I don get any error message. Just a warning saying: "Package hyperref Warning: Option `backref' has already been used,". I edited the original post including a MWE. I modified it accordingly to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43377 but it still doesn't works like I whish. This is what I would like to have: when I click on [1] I'm redirected to the Bibliography page, and this is quite obvious. I would like to have the possibility to come back to the point of \cite{itemi1} by clicking on [1] “Information Management: a Proposal” (1989) in the Bibliography page.

Comment: @nplatis In this document I use \cite only once for each bibitem.

Comment: @nplatis makes a very good point about the use of `pagebackref`.

Comment: @hpesoj626 Yes, you're right, but instead of having back references printed as page numbers after each entry, I would like to use the title of the entry, for e.g. in my MWE the back reference should be possible by clicking on [1] “Information Management: a Proposal” ...is it possible or not?